# É necessário criar uma app para cada entidade em um projeto Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Gostaria de saber se é uma boa prática ou se é uma atitude muito "extrema".

Exemplo: Meu projeto tem as entidades usuario,cliente,assinatura e produtos. Posso criar uma app com todas essas entidades ou devo criar uma app para cada?

Comment: Ola, William.
Cara para ser sincero eu nunca ouvi, nem vi falar que o ideal é criar uma app para cada entidade, porém quando estou desenvolvendo meus projetos eu levo. Considerando o tamanho do sistema, se for ter muitas entidadades eu costumo criar as apps para elas, já se for uma aplicação pequena com poucas entidades, eu gosto de criar uma app core, e fazer tudo por ela mesmo, que para mim não fica muito bagunçado o código.

Comment: Por "entidades", vc quer dizer `models`? Se for não é uma 'atitude muito "extrema"' é: **I N S A N O**

Answer (score 0):

Cara, depende muito, mas de modo geral, eu gosto de dividir minha aplicação em módulos, por exemplo, no caso de um e-commerce, eu criaria um app chamado "categorias", outro chamado "produtos", eu acho melhor do que criar um único app e um models.py gigantesco.